# Problems with removing item from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me why this is not working corectly?
I want a function that will remove list item when I click on it - instead it is removing the whole list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#add-tag" ).on("click", function(x) {
        var tag = $("#new-tag").val();

        $("#galleries div:first-child").clone().appendTo("#galleries");

        $("#galleries-list").append('<li>' + tag + ' gallery: <a href="#"> remove</a></li>');
        $("#new-tag").removeAttr("value");
        x.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#galleries-list li a").on("click", function(x) {
        var elem = $(this);
        $(elem).remove();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 3):

make it

```
$("#galleries-list li a").on("click", function(x) {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.parent().remove(); //since you want to remove the li on click of a
});
```

it was already a jquery object, you didn't have to make it again.

Comment: Note: You can be more specific to with `elem.parent("li").remove();`

Comment: @Twisty I agree with you. I'll leave it to OP to understand and make this change. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this as well - still doesnt working, maybe there is something wrong with appending li element to the ul? html looks like this              `<ul id="galleries-list">
  <li>html gallery:<a href=""> remove</a></li>
  <li>css gallery:<a href=""> remove</a></li>    
</ul>`

Comment: @ŁukaszSamulnik can you try putting e.preventDefault() after removing the element? if not working can you share a fiddle?

Comment: @ŁukaszSamulnik it is removing the list element in your fiddle on my browser.

Comment: but i cannot create new one and remove it after

Comment: @lukaszsamulnik adding an item is not part of your original question. However gimme some time for that.

Comment: I know, but this is what isnt working now. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/88t09ma8/2/

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add-tag").on("click", function(x) {
    x.preventDefault(); // Keep form from submitting
    var tag = $("#new-tag").val();
    $("#galleries div:first-child").clone().appendTo("#galleries");
    $("#galleries-list").append('<li>' + tag + ' gallery: <a href="#"> remove</a></li>');
  });

  $(document).on("click", "ul#galleries-list li a", function(x) {
    $("#new-tag").val("");
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

The `.on()` was not hooking to the dynamically created link, so I had to select it more specifically. Also `tag` was not defined.